# Stop tracking a file in git from a timepoint on while keeping old tracked commits

Tags: git, github, gitlab

A friend asked me for a way to untrack a file from a time point on for the future - but being able to git checkup to a state where the file was still tracked by git.
Aim is to keep the file locally but prevent for future commits

I googled in the past for this - and read several stackoverflow answers to similar problems.

But it seems that there is no good way to achieve this.

It seems that the tracking status of files is globally controlled. Is there a way to keep the tracking status locally controlled (meaning can be changed from commit to commit)?

Comment: Hm? Remove the file from git and add it to .gitignore. Git will stop tracking this file.

Comment: That is a weird/confusing title :)

Comment: @AD7six probably I just misunderstood git

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> But it seems that there is no good way to achieve this.

That's correct, and it's kind of a fundamental problem.  The issue here is that a file that is not tracked (at any given point in time) is one that **does** exist in the *working tree*, but **does not** exist in Git's index—and the only part that's actually *in* Git, here, is Git's index.

If and when you check out some old commit, where the file *is* in the commit, Git must:

- extract the file to Git's index **and**
- extract the file into your working tree

which means that if there *was* an untracked file in your working tree under that name, it must be destroyed, so that the committed version can be extracted.  If it *is* extracted successfully at this point, it is now in both your working tree (which isn't in Git) *and* in Git's index, and is a *tracked* file.

The previous untracked file is, by definition, destroyed, unless there's some not-in-Git (e.g., OS-level) method of re-obtaining a nominally deleted-and-replaced file.<sup>1</sup>  For this reason, Git will normally *object* to the idea of destroying some untracked file.  A `git checkout` or `git switch` that would destroy such a file stops with an error instead, telling you that the file needs to be saved somehow first, unless you use the `--force` option.

Unfortunately, listing a file in `.gitignore`—as you might wish to do to keep it from *accidentally* becoming tracked—gives Git *permission to destroy the file*.  This is a longstanding known weakness in Git; the Git developer community would like to have some method of marking some file path as both "do not track a la the usual `.gitignore` style" and "precious, do not destroy either".  As of today (Git 2.39 or so) there is still no way to do this.

---

<sup>1</sup>Many modern file systems offer a method of doing this with what the file systems call *snapshots*.  You pick some point in time and say "make a file system snapshot", and you can then roll the file system back to that point in time.  This is the same kind of idea that version control systems implement, except that it's done on a per-file-system basis.

The details behind the FS snapshot method get complicated.  For instance, MacOS "time machine" is very different from UFS or ZFS snapshots.  The idea itself is pretty simple though: all the before-snapshot file versions are saved for some time period ("all time" or "until the snapshot expires" or whatever), and by using the "extract previous snapshot" software—whatever that may be—you *can* get the file back.  But this is all outside Git.

Comment: Yes, thank you for the detailed answer! I think there must be a "tracked, but not committed to any other repo - especially a remote repo" - a truly local git. Currently probably only realizable by generating a submodule which is completely private.

Answer (score 4):

> It seems that the tracking status of files is globally controlled

No, it doesn't.

> Is there a way to keep the tracking status locally controlled (meaning can be changed from commit to commit)?

No, because that is not what tracking is. None of what you've said is what tracking is.

A file is *tracked* because it is present in the index. That's basically all there is to it. It is present in the index because either (1) it is present in the currently checked out commit (aka HEAD) or (2) you have created the file and added it to the index (with `git add`). This definition is completely automatic and autonomous.

So how can you make a tracked file untracked? On a rather obvious and crude level, since the whole definition of "tracked" depends on the index, you can simply remove the file from the index (with `git rm`).

There is also an exclusion mechanism: you can use a `.gitignore` file. But this has no effect whatever on what I've already said. It merely lists exceptions to broad actions, saying that if a new file of a certain type should appear, it should not be *added to the index* when you give a global command such as `git add .`, and it should not be *listed* among the new untracked files when you say `git status`.

Comment: true, I didn't understood it deeply enough obviously. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

To stop tracking the file `git rm file_name`

To keep the file from being tracked,
add the filename to .gitignore

Comment: It is a valid answer. But I think I see that the problem is another. After `git checkout` to other commits - and then comming back - the ignored file is not existent in local repo neither.

Comment: Slowly I think - the original person asking me that - did not formulate the actual problem correctly.

Comment: thank you though - it is a valid answer actually.